# Compute the complexity of the following Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Compute the complexity of the following Algorithm?

I have the following code snippet:

```
i = 1;
while (i < n + 1) {
    j = 1;
    while (j < n + 1) {
        j = j * 2;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

plz explain it in detail

I want to know the the steps to solve the problem so I can solve such problems

Comment: Inner loop takes `O(log(n))`, since `j` grows exponentially. Outer loop takes `O(n)` since `i` grows linearly. Hence the overall complexity is `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: @Jarod42: OP most likely meant `i<n+1`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Haha, no, there's a minimum length for comments here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i = 1;
while(i < n + 1){
    j = 1;
    While(j < n + 1){
        j = j * 2:
    }

    i = i + 1;
}
```

outer loop takes O(n) since it increments by constant.

```
i = 1;
while(i < n + 1){

    i = i + 1;
}
```

inner loop : j = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...., 2^k
j = 2^k (k >= 0) 
when will j stops ?
when j == n,
log(2^k) = log(n)
=> k * lg(2) = lg(n) ..... so k = lg(n).

```
While(j < n + 1){

        j = j * 2;
}
```

so total O(n * lg(n))

Answer (score 8):

Since `j` grows exponentially, the inner loop takes `O(log(n))`.

Since `i` grows linearly, the outer loop takes `O(n)`.

Hence the overall complexity is `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: +1 for succinct, correct answer and proper use of math-words.

Comment: @Conduit: Thanks :) ... What does *succinct* mean by the way?

Comment: Thank you so much Barak manos , but go in more detail :p

Comment: @sangeen: More details?? It's kinda hard considering the sheer size of your code...

Comment: @sangeen: Sorry, but I don't think that this website is meant for people to provide other people with answers sufficient for full marks given to them by their teachers. I provided you with a basic answer (plus an up-vote to your question, by the way), and I think it is reasonable enough for you to do the rest of the job here.

Comment: @barakmanos very clear and short/to-the-point

Comment: @Conduit: Right, well, that's exactly what I tried to explain to OP in one of the comments above :)

Comment: @barakmanos Weren't you aware that we are a homework machine? Question in, A+ out, hehe.

Comment: @Conduit: Yeah, well... I don't really have a problem with that to be honest, but in this case, asking for any more details within the answer feels a bit like... kinda greedy if you know what I mean...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply understand outer-loop(with `i`) because it loops exactly `n` times. (1, 2, 3, ..., n). But inner-loop(`j`) is little difficult to understand.

Let's assume that `n` is 8. How much it loops? Starting with `j = 1`, it will be increased as exponentially : 1, 2, 4, 8. When `j` is over 8, loop will be terminated. It loops exactly 4 times. Then we can think general-form of this problem...

Think of that sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, .... If `n` is 2^k (k is non-negative integer), inner-loop will take `k+1` times. (Because 2^(loop-1) = 2^k) Due to the assumption : `n = 2^k`, we can say that `k = lg(n)`. So we can say inner-loop takes `lg(n)+1` times.

When `n` is not exactly fit to 2^k, it takes one more time. (`[lg(n)]+1`) It's not a big deal with complexity though it has floor function. You can ingonre it this time.

So the total costs will be like this : `n*(lg(n)+1)`. If you are familiar with Big-O notation, it can be expressed as : `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: Oh I wrote this to slowly....

Comment: It doesn't matter , at last you helped some people to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This one is similar to the following code :

```
for( int i = 1;i < n+1 ; i++){ // this loop runs n times
    for(int j = 1 ; j<n+1 ; j=j*2){// this loop runs log_2(n)(log base 2 because it grows exponentially with 2)
      //body
    }
}
```

Hence in Big-Oh notation it is O(n)*O(logn) ; i.e, O(n*logn)

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like the following:

[image]

Comment: how cn * log(n+1) = O(n) ?

Comment: A small mistake, sorry.